# Building a weight scale

Tags: pic, load-cell, barcode

I need to build a scale that is able to get an input from a load cell, get an input from a bar-code scanner (i don't know if this is to be treated  like a keyboard or if there is a more native way to use the inputs), and one output.

What chip is best suited for these requirements? at first i was thinking of working with PIC16F648A, but it does not hold native support for USB interface, and i am not sure if that's a real problem (referring to the keyboard/bar-code reader problem i have above).

the output is displayed on an LCD, and should be able to print it out  if needed.

Comment: You can get barcode scanners that output RS232 or PS/2 keyboard protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TI [has a block diagram and application notes for a weigh scale](http://www.ti.com/solution/weigh_scale) that might be a starting point. Also, read this app note by Analog Devices: [Precision WeighScale Design Using the AD7192 24-Bit Sigma-Delta ADC 
with Internal PGA](http://www.analog.com/en/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0119/vc.html).

You can also [find barcode scanners](http://www.barcodesinc.com/cats/barcode-scanners/rs232.htm) that support RS-232 (easier to interface to a microcontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a circuit I've used a few times for weight, strain and pressure gauges: -

[image]

The bridge is fed from a constant current supply - this alleviates some non-linearities if the bridge is only half active i.e. two of the four resistor change value with weight. Vref imparts a voltage across the BJT emitter resistor which pushes a constant current into the bridge.

The input is sensed with an instrumentation amplifier such as the AD8221. It can have its output offsetted by a DAC when auto-balancing (you'll probably need that feature). You need to ensure your offset is made slightly positive to make life easier for your ADC if it is powered from a positive supply and ground.

Make sure your auto-balance DAC output is nicely decoupled with an RC filter to prevent any significant clock-feed-through into the analogue stuff.

Its output feeds an ADC of your choice. Gain of the AD8221 is set with Rg.

Can't help you with the barcode stuff but other will I'm sure.